# Extract information from OSM given GPS point

Tags: gps, overpass-api, route, map-matching

I have a little problem with the extraction of road information from OSM.

I explain my setup: I have several GPS points, extracted every 1 sec and the final goal is to extract information about the ways of my route; I use OverpassTurbo API to obtain them.

Firstly, I tried to match the ways to the GPS points by choosing the OSM nodes closest to each GPS point (computing euclidean distance) and then using an algorithm I select the way between two consecutive nodes.

However, this method doesn't work fine if I have a set of GPS points very close, because can happen that a GPS point of a very long path is closest to a OSM node that belong to another way. So, to overcome this, I have tried to use the query way[highway](around: radius, lat, lon) and for each GPS point find the way that is inside the radius. This last method works fine, but it is very slow since it makes a request for each point, until a way is found.

Does someone have an idea to solve my problem?